# Matrix multiplication - C++

Tags: c++, matrix

```
void power(int a[][21], int n, int d) {
    int e[21][21], k, i, j, l;

    if (d == 1) {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                cout << a[i][j] << " ";

            cout << endl;
        }    
    } else {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                e[i][j] = 0;

        for (l = 1; l < d; l++)
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
                        e[i][j] = e[i][j] + (a[i][k] * a[k][j]);

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                cout << e[i][j] << " ";

            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to build a function that calculates the power of a matrix. The program works for the 1st and 2nd power of the matrix but if I want to calculate the 3rd power the function will return incorrect values. I think the problem is at retaining the previous results but I can't figure out on how to fix it.

Comment: _"but I can't figure out on how to fix it"_ Easily. You use a debugger, step through your code line by line, and check how values are changing. If you found the place where values change in an unexpected way, you've caught the source of your logical error. Isn't that wonderful?

Comment: why do you iterate from index 1 in every loop?

Comment: For the powers after 2, you are still only using the values from `a`, rather than also involving the results from `e`. Follow @πάνταῥεῖ's advice on debugging; it requires that you know how the values are expected to change, so you should start by working out (on paper) how you expect the computation to proceed. Most likely, this exercise will show how your code doesn't use the previous results (as you say).

Comment: @LogicStuff ... and to extend: Why are you using `i <= n` as the loop condition? Should be `i < n` because `n` isn't a valid index.

Comment: It's really terrible to see how many haters and trolls exist on StackOverflow. It's clear that he tried to find a solution and did not manage to, which is why he looked for help here. Now, if you guys can help then I suggest you do and I don't see how the downvotes are helpful in this scenario. Clearly encouraging a beginner and upvoting the answer is the better way to act in this community.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu *Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be.* http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @NeilKirk I think the *expected behavior* would be that a matrix multiplication operation is correct. Also, he did describe the problem, but now I guess that if he knew all of the details of the problem then he wouldn't be posting the question, don't you agree?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Where is a sample input, expected output and actual output? *"I  think the problem is at retaining the previous results"* No specific details are given of debug work so far.

Comment: @NeilKirk Congratulations on assuming that everyone knows (especially a beginner) what a debugger is.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Stack Overflow is not specifically a beginners' website. It's reasonable to assume that posters have at least passing familiarity with the tools they are using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73960/discussion-between-radu-gheorghiu-and-neil-kirk).

Comment: No. I don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

This block of code

```
    for (l = 1; l < d; l++)
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
                    e[i][j] = e[i][j] + (a[i][k] * a[k][j]);
```

sets `e` to be `a*a` no matter what `d` is.

You need to have a temporary matrix to make things work.

Bootstrap:

```
e = a;
```

In the loop:

```
temp = e;
e = temp * a;

temp = e;
e = temp * a;
```

... etc.

Something along the lines of:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
   {
      e[i][j] = a[i][j];
   }
}


for (l = 1; l < d; l++)
{
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      {
         temp[i][j] = e[i][j];
      }
   }

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      {
         e[i][j] = 0;
         for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
         {
            e[i][j] += (temp[i][k] * a[k][j]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**PS** I have used `0`-based indexing to access the matrices. I am not sure why you have used `1`-based indexing.